# Fullscreen Mode exiting

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have the following anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" onclick="launchFullscreen(document.documentElement);">Full-screen</a>
```

Which uses the following lines of code that I've gathered from a tutorial:

```
<script>
    // Find the right method, call on correct element
    function launchFullscreen(element) {
        if (element.requestFullscreen) {
            element.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
            element.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }

    function exitFullscreen() {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (element.msExitFullscreen) {
            element.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    }

    function dumpFullscreen() {
        console.log("document.fullscreenElement is: ", document.fullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement);
        console.log("document.fullscreenEnabled is: ", document.fullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullScreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled || document.msFullscreenEnabled);
    }
    // Events
    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function (e) {
        console.log("fullscreenchange event! ", e);
    });
    document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function (e) {
        console.log("mozfullscreenchange event! ", e);
    });
    document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function (e) {
        console.log("webkitfullscreenchange event! ", e);
    });
    document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", function (e) {
        console.log("msfullscreenchange event! ", e);
    });
    // Add different events for full-screen
</script>
```

This works perfectly fine to enter full-screen mode, however when the user leaves the page (by clicking a link), it will exit full-screen mode.

Is there a way that I can make the website stay in the full-screen mode once the anchor tag is clicked, and then only exit this mode only when the ESC button or Full-screen hyperlink is pushed again?

Comment: Hmmm, my thoughts are you need an active-x plugin to maintain that... and most people don't like installing that. Good luck!

Comment: Probably an iframe, AJAX or something similar, so that when you navigate to a different page, your html element doesn't actually change/refresh.

Comment: I think ajax would be the best approach here like Shomz pointed out

Comment: Yes, perhaps AJAX.  But more specifically, how would I integrate this?  A live demonstration of the tutorial can be found here - http://davidwalsh.name/demo/fullscreen.php

Comment: No. Ajax or activex/iframe hacks are the only way. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/fullscreen/#toc-keepuserin Even in the demo you posted, as soon as you click a nav bar link, you exit fullscreen mode. If you have a question about converting a static site to an 'ajax site', I'd post another question with sample code or a link to the site in question.

Comment: You won't have to worry about fullscreen if you use AJAX. You only goal would be to update a DOM element with a result from an AJAX call.

Comment: it might be because of `href="#"`.. check by removing it or use `div` instead of anchor tag.

Comment: You can use `history.pushState()`/AJAX to do this too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the URL changes, full screen mode is canceled. The only non-hack-y way can prevent this by happening is by using a SPA, **S**ingle **P**age **A**pplication, library which manages state by using the fragment url (`#fragment`) to circumvent this issue. Here are some good ones:

- [pagerjs](http://pagerjs.com/)
- [routie](http://projects.jga.me/routie)
- [crossroads](http://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/)

If you want to go all out you can use an MVC framework which supports fragment routing:

- [Angular](http://angularjs.org/)
- [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)